# INSERT + SELECT data type mismatch on similar fields

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert, primary-key, system.data.sqlite

I'm running the following SQLite workaround to add a primary key to a table that did not have one. I am getting a datatype mismatch on

```sql
INSERT INTO cities 
SELECT id, name FROM old_cities;
```

However, the fields have exactly the same type. Is it possible that his happens due to running the queries from DbBrowser for SQLite?

```sql
CREATE table cities (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO cities (id, name)
VALUES ('pan', 'doul');

END TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE cities RENAME TO old_cities;

--CREATE TABLE cities (
--   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
--   name TEXT NOT NULL
--);


CREATE TABLE cities (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

SELECT * FROM old_cities;

INSERT INTO cities 
SELECT id, name FROM old_cities;

DROP TABLE old_cities;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the column `id` of the table `cities` to be `INTEGER`, but with this:

```
INSERT INTO cities (id, name) VALUES ('pan', 'doul');
```

you insert the string `'pan'` as `id`.
SQLite does not do any type checking in this case and allows it.

Did you mean to insert 2 rows each having the names `'pan'` and `'doul'`?
If so, you should do something like:

```
INSERT INTO cities (id, name) VALUES (1, 'pan'), (2, 'doul');
```

Later you rename the table `cities` to `old_cities` and you recreate `cities`  but you do something different: you define `id` as `INTEGER` and `PRIMARY KEY`.
This definition is the only one that forces type checking in SQLite.

So, when you try to insert the rows from `old_cities` to `cities` you get an error because `'pan'` is not allowed in the column     `id` as it is defined now.